# Show that same cardinal number defines and equivalence relation

Tags: cardinals, equivalence-relations

Same cardinal number must satisfy all three properties : symmetry, reflexivity, transitivity

Symmetry

Suppose bijection $f:A→A$, Then by definition, |A| = |A|

Reflexivity

Suppose bijections $f:A→B$ and $f:B→A$, Then |A| = |B| and |B| = |A|

Transitivity

Suppose bijections $f:A→B$ and $f:B→C$ Then |A|= |B| and |B| = |C|

I think I did this right but I feel as though this is too simple of a proof or I have the definitions wrong

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the proposed solution is not right. For reflexivity, one must show there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ to $A$.  It is not hard to show that $f(x)=x$ works. For symmetry, we must show that if $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$, there is a bijection from $B$ to $A$. There is an obvious candidate. Transitivity is along similar lines, but longer.

Comment: For transitivity you need to show that if there is a bijection $f:A\to B$ and a bijection $g: B\to C$ then there is also a bijection $h:A\to C$. This is easiest done by explicitly constructing the bijection needed and proving that it works. For transitivity an obvious thing to try is $h(x) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: Using the same letter $f$ for different functions  within the same context is not a good practice.